# Scrollable option makes rows extend outside of Kendo grid when viewed on mobile

Tags: kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

I am creating a Telerik Kendo Grid and if I set .Scrollable to false it makes the header poke out of the grid.

[image]

If it is set to true the grid behaves as expected:

[image]

I'm thinking it may be a bug in the grid. Any ideas? Thanks.